# C Linux Cross compilation

Tags: embedded-linux

Compiling a test C programme(Below) with linaro-arm-linux toolchain on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and running on target, it works fine,
but if i do the same on Ubuntu 11.10 and run it on target, it throws error. Error: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")”.

## lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

## lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric

```
Example      
int main()  
{                
printf("Hello World");   
return 0;          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do 
i.e compile file.c with linaro-arm-toolchain and chmod 777 a.out(I imagine a.out is executable here).Then try to move to target and run .

Comment: No, this is not the issue , and if you are compiling for other platform you can't execute on ubuntu.

Comment: I did't suggest to execute in ubuntu .I told to run in target sir

Answer (score 0):

> syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")

This message looks like a shell error, rather than a C runtime error.
If you were running the binary from a shell script, can you double-check its syntax, especially the [shebang](https://duckduckgo.com/Shebang_%28Unix%29?ia=about) line ?

Comment: yes it's a shell error but , if i compile the same with \bin\bash then it work fine only problem with bin\dash.